# how to implement interface of circlemenu in xamarin android?

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, interface, xamarin.android

i have been trying to implement interface in circlemenu library available via nuget:

https://github.com/Hitomis/CircleMenu

in my xamarin android project i am unable to call and implement interface inside circle menu method **.SetOnMenuStatusChangeListener(....) & .SetOnMenuStatusChangeListener(....)**

here is my xamarin c# code

```
public class mainMenuActivity : Activity,IOnMenuStatusChangeListener,IOnMenuSelectedListener
{
    CircleMenu circleMenu = null;
    public void OnMenuClosed()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnMenuOpened()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnMenuSelected(int p0)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "selected " + p0, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.mainmenu);
        var circleMenu = FindViewById<CircleMenu>(Resource.Id.circle_menu);
        circleMenu.SetMainMenu(Color.ParseColor("#98ccfd"), Resource.Mipmap.menu, Resource.Mipmap.cancel)
            .AddSubMenu(Color.ParseColor("#258CFF"), Resource.Mipmap.scanner)
    .AddSubMenu(Color.ParseColor("#30A400"), Resource.Mipmap.mapmarker)
    .AddSubMenu(Color.ParseColor("#fe9b93"), Resource.Mipmap.support)
    .AddSubMenu(Color.ParseColor("#25b7d3"), Resource.Mipmap.share)
    .AddSubMenu(Color.ParseColor("#f44336"), Resource.Mipmap.shutdown);
        //.SetOnMenuStatusChangeListener();
        this.circleMenu = circleMenu; 
    }
}
```

Apparently implementing the interface on class level doesnt bind it with circlemenu please guide.

here is the java version of supposed code

```
     circleMenu = (CircleMenu) findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);

     circleMenu.setMainMenu(Color.parseColor("#CDCDCD"), R.mipmap.icon_menu, 
     R.mipmap.icon_cancel)
    .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#258CFF"), R.mipmap.icon_home)
    .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#30A400"), R.mipmap.icon_search)
    .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF4B32"), R.mipmap.icon_notify)
    .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#8A39FF"), R.mipmap.icon_setting)
    .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.mipmap.icon_gps)
    .setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMenuSelected(int index) {}

    }).setOnMenuStatusChangeListener(new OnMenuStatusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMenuOpened() {}

        @Override
        public void onMenuClosed() {}

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "implement an interface"? There's no code here that shows an interface.

Comment: @DavidG please look at the library in nuget IOnMenuStatusChangeListener,IOnMenuSelectedListener is interface in c# port of  circlemenu lib